What config file does qt5ct update?
In Ubuntu 24.04, qt5ct crashes if I try to change Style to gtk2.  I;ve opened a bug on this.
But,  meanwhile, does anyone know what config file(s) qt5ct updates when chaning the Style?  I just want virtualbox to work in Dark Mode.
Help?

Ubuntu 24.04 (noble) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the development release Ubuntu noble and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu noble you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

That may be true, however, two points:  1.)  24.04 is now less than a week away from release, so I think I'll leave this here.  2.)  The solution is applicable to previous releases of Ubuntu, maaking it relevant today.

Ok, I figured it out the old school way:
strings `which qt5ct`|grep '/' |more

I looked through the output and spotted:
qt5ct.conf

So, I did:
sudo find / -name qt5ct.conf

and it returned:
/home/mjb/.config/qt5ct/qt5ct.conf

I edited it, and in the first section, [Appearance], the last item was style=Fusion.  I changed it to style=gtk2 and saved the file.
Now when I run virtualbox, it comes up in dark mode, like the rest of my system. Voila!
